# Setting angularjs ng-model value by an object value

Tags: angularjs

I have an input text on my html side,

```
   <input ng-model="item.valueProperty"
       ng-disabled="item.options.length>0"
       type="text"
       placeholder="List item value"
       class="form-control"
       required>
```

if `item.options` array has any item, my textbox value (`item.valueProperty`) will be set as `key` 
But I want to this on html side via `ng-` directives.

I can not set it on javascript controller. is this possible?

Comment: Can you explain what problem you are facing.

Comment: setting input value by options lenght. if it has items value of `item.valueProperty` will be "key"

Comment: if it has items value of item.valueProperty will be "key" ?

Comment: item.valueProperty is a model. model value will be set as "key" text.

Comment: ng-model="item.valueProperty" is correct syntax to bind ng-model. I stilldon't know what issue you are facing.

Comment: if I type something in textbox, `item.valueProperty` wil be change ok? But I want that if `item.options.length>0` it will be change as "key" text automatically.

Comment: I guess you got the answer posted below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you wantL

```js
angular.module('test', [])
  .controller('test', function ($scope) {
    $scope.item = {
      valueProperty: 'Test',
      options: [1]
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="test">
<input ng-model="item.valueProperty"
       ng-disabled="item.options.length > 0 ? item.valueProperty='key' : false"
       type="text"
       placeholder="List item value"
       class="form-control"
       required>
</div>
```

I just set $scope.item.valueProperty to 'key' if item.options.length > 0 in ng-disabled directive, `item.options.length > 0 ? item.valueProperty=123 : false`is a valid expression, so it will work.

Comment: Yes it is thanks, so I learned to set model values on html side.

Comment: Yes, but seems to be a bad practice, try to use controllers. Enjoy it!